# Shell script - How can I have a while inside of while populating data?

Tags: shell

Can you please help-me? I appreciate any assistance!

I have this file:

```
[root@acnode1 tmp]# cat nodeidhost.out
               node_id                | hostname
 c31abf5a-ece5-4da5-afa3-1af4e19f9749 | acnode1.storagedomain
 c41bcebe-37a3-42ce-8ded-249b2726ca17 | acnode2.storagedomain
 5b00247c-f38c-4c8e-9835-a8b935549267 | acnode3.storagedomain
 10a69825-38d8-4675-b845-906d94a99ec8 | acnode4.storagedomain
 f2cb6d0f-54fa-4c70-ac02-65ff8aca9edc | acnode5.storagedomain
```

And this file:

```
[root@acnode1 tmp]# cat nodeidversion.out
               node_id                | installed_version | available_version
 c31abf5a-ece5-4da5-afa3-1af4e19f9749 | 4.5.0-284         | 4.5.0-284
 c41bcebe-37a3-42ce-8ded-249b2726ca17 | 4.5.0-284         | 4.5.0-284
 5b00247c-f38c-4c8e-9835-a8b935549267 | 4.5.0-284         | 4.5.0-284
 10a69825-38d8-4675-b845-906d94a99ec8 | 4.5.0-284         | 4.5.0-284
 f2cb6d0f-54fa-4c70-ac02-65ff8aca9edc | 4.5.0-284         | 4.5.0-284
```

I am trying to create a while inside of while, so on the first while the 'nodeidhost.out' loads the ID (first column) and Hostname (second column), but I need also to check the file 'nodeidversion.out' to check what is the 'installed_version' and 'available_version' and merge these details:

Note: The 'node_id' column is the 'master key' to make a comparison:

```
while read nodeid; do
        node_id=`echo $nodeid | awk '{print $1}'`
        node_name=`echo $nodeid | awk '{print $3}' | cut -d"." -f1`
        .... second while checking 'installed_version' and 'available_version' from 'nodeidversion.out'
done < /tmp/nodeidhost.out
```

At the end I need something like:

Node XXXX is running version YYYY and latest version is ZZZZ

Can you please help me? Thank you!!

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem Please provide sample output. I suspect you're going about this in the wrong way by jumping to the conclusion that you should use nested while-loops.

Comment: Are both files sorted the same way? Will the node on line N of the first file match on line N of the second file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making life too complicated by trying to manually parse the files with nested while loops. Meet the `join` command:

```
Usage: join [OPTION]... FILE1 FILE2
For each pair of input lines with identical join fields, write a line to
standard output.  The default join field is the first, delimited by blanks.
...
```

See `man join` for more information. Example usage to solve your problem:

```
$ join -t'|' -j1 -o 1.2,2.2,2.3 --header nodeid* | column -s'|' -o' | ' -t
 hostname              |  installed_version  |  available_version
 acnode1.storagedomain |  4.5.0-284          |  4.5.0-284
 acnode2.storagedomain |  4.5.0-284          |  4.5.0-284
 acnode3.storagedomain |  4.5.0-284          |  4.5.0-284
 acnode4.storagedomain |  4.5.0-284          |  4.5.0-284
 acnode5.storagedomain |  4.5.0-284          |  4.5.0-284
```

Explanation of flags:

- `-t'|'` specifies that the input files are pipe-delimited.
- `-j1` causes the join to be on the first field of both files. (It's actually redundant here because the default is to join on the first field.)
- `-o 1.2,2.2,2.3` specifies output format of file 1, column 2, followed by columns 2 and 3 from file 2.
- `--header` because the files have headers ... I don't think it makes a difference here, but it doesn't hurt.
- `| column ... (etc)` Just a bit of post-processing to tidy up the column alignment, since join discards that information from the input.

**NB: The join command does assume the input was sorted. Use the sort command to preprocess the input.**

Answer (score 0):

**If** the nodes correspond on matching lines like your sample shows, you can use a shell while loop reading from both files at the same time:

```bsh
while
    IFS=$' \t|' read -r node1 host <&3
    IFS=$' \t|' read -r node2 ver1 ver2 <&4
do
    [[ "$node1" == "$node2" ]] || { echo "lines mismatched"; break; }
    echo "$node1 => $host => $ver1 => $ver2"
done 3<nodeidhost.out \
     4<nodeidversion.out
```

outputs

```
node_id => hostname => installed_version => available_version
c31abf5a-ece5-4da5-afa3-1af4e19f9749 => acnode1.storagedomain => 4.5.0-284 => 4.5.0-284
c41bcebe-37a3-42ce-8ded-249b2726ca17 => acnode2.storagedomain => 4.5.0-284 => 4.5.0-284
5b00247c-f38c-4c8e-9835-a8b935549267 => acnode3.storagedomain => 4.5.0-284 => 4.5.0-284
10a69825-38d8-4675-b845-906d94a99ec8 => acnode4.storagedomain => 4.5.0-284 => 4.5.0-284
f2cb6d0f-54fa-4c70-ac02-65ff8aca9edc => acnode5.storagedomain => 4.5.0-284 => 4.5.0-284
```

Otherwise, awk is a good choice

```bsh
awk -F '[[:blank:]]+[|][[:blank:]]+' '
    FNR == 1 {next}
    NR == FNR {host[$1] = $2; next}
    $1 in host {printf "%s => %s => %s => %s\n", $1, host[$1], $2, $3}
' nodeidhost.out hostidversion.out
```